# Get image from external server

Tags: c#, asp.net

We are storing our images at Amazon S3. Let's say the location is http://media.sitename.com/folder1/image1.jpg.

I want to copy this file and store it in our server. Is it possible to do this using C#. I am using asp.net 4.0.

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go:

```
using (var client = new WebClient()) 
{ 
    client.DownloadFile(imageURL, localPathname);
}
```

where `imageURL` is http://media.sitename.com/folder1/image1.jpg and `localPathname` is something like C:\my\images\directory\cachedImage.jpg

Answer (score 3):

[Download Image using c#](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0580__Network/Downloadimagefromawebsite.htm)

[Download image from Web](http://snipplr.com/view/15105/c-download-image-from-web/)

Just Google/Bing "Download Image from server using c#" and you will get many more links.

Comment: First link is cool, because it doesn't require to save picture like a file and we can with with image everything what we want